# Using mutex for pthread results in random answer

Tags: c, pthreads, mutex

I have written a simple pthread code which

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

#define ITERATIONS 500

// A shared mutex
pthread_mutex_t mutex;
int target;

void* opponent(void *arg)
{
  int i;
  printf("opp, before for target=%d\n", target);
  pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
  for(i = 0; i < ITERATIONS; ++i)
  {
    target++;
  }
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
  printf("opp, after for target=%d\n", target);

  return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  pthread_t other;

  target = 5;

  // Initialize the mutex
  if(pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, NULL))
  {
    printf("Unable to initialize a mutex\n");
    return -1;
  }

  if(pthread_create(&other, NULL, &opponent, NULL))
  {
    printf("Unable to spawn thread\n");
    return -1;
  }

  int i;
  printf("main, before for target=%d\n", target);
  pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
  for(i = 0; i < ITERATIONS; ++i)
  {
    target--;
  }
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
  printf("main, after for target=%d\n", target);

  if(pthread_join(other, NULL))
  {
    printf("Could not join thread\n");
    return -1;
  }

  // Clean up the mutex
  pthread_mutex_destroy(&mutex);

  printf("Result: %d\n", target);

  return 0;
}
```

Then I compile with this command

```
gcc -pedantic -Wall -o theaded_program pth.c -lpthread
```

However, every time I run the program, I get different results!!

```
 $ ./theaded_program
 main, before for target=5
 main, after for target=-495
 opp, before for target=5
 opp, after for target=5
 Result: 5

 $ ./theaded_program
 main, before for target=5
 opp, before for target=5
 opp, after for target=5
 main, after for target=-495
 Result: 5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `printf()` statements are not executed when the mutex is locked and they are accessing `target`:

```
printf("opp, before for target=%d\n", target);
pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
```

This means one thread is potentially changing the value of `target` while another thread is attempting to read it (in the `printf()`). Move the `printf()` statements to be executed when the mutex is locked:

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
printf("opp, before for target=%d\n", target);
/* snip */
printf("opp, after for target=%d\n", target);
pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
```

This will prevent `target` being read by one thread and modified by another concurrently. However, there is no guarantee which thread will first acquire the mutex.

Comment: What is the solution then?

Answer (score 1):

This result is as expected, your code guarantees that main and opponent are not doing

```
for(i = 0; i < ITERATIONS; ++i)
{
  target--; //or ++ for the opponent
}
```

at the same time.

The `printf`s are not in any way protected by the mutex. To avoid this insert the `printf`s within the mutex lock/unlock